# Round error when plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have the following array of data:

```
In [53]: data
Out[53]: array([  9.95000000e-05,   9.95000000e-05,   9.95000000e-05,
         ...
         ...
         9.95000000e-05])
```

When I do a plot of it i get:

[image]

I would expect the plot to be a straight line with something meaningful on the y axis. What is the cause for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `9.95000000e-05` is actually `9.9500000000000006e-05` or `9.9499999999999979e-05` or some simmilar number which iPython rounds for the sake of clarity.

Matplotlib, however, acknowledge the number in its complete precision which as a result has the unexpected behaviour.

The workaround or this is to round the number to the values represented in iPython.

```
In [53]: round(data,7)
Out[53]: array([  9.95000000e-05,   9.95000000e-05,   9.95000000e-05,
         ... 
         ...
         ])
```

Which provides a nice plot:

```
In [54]: plot(round(data,7))
```

[image]

Comment: How come you could answer your question so soon..?

Comment: I disagree with @SaulloCastro Leaving your answer as non-wiki is fine.